# Fetch Data Array from CoreData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have data stored in Code Data with a table called Users. I am simply trying to pull the "FirstName" from the array of data returned but keep getting "nil" in my console.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Users")

let fetchedResults =
```

managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
    error: &error) as? [Users]

```
    var arrayvalues=NSArray(array: fetchedResults!)

    if let results = managedObject?.executeFetchRequest(fetchedResults, error: nil) as? [Users] {
        let someObject = results[firstName]
    }
```

My user class looks like:

```
class Users: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var email: String
@NSManaged var firstName: String
@NSManaged var fLast: String
@NSManaged var fullName: String
@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var isActive: String
@NSManaged var lastName: String
@NSManaged var lastupdated: String
@NSManaged var role: String
@NSManaged var uPass: String

}
```

I've been looking for ways to achieve this but cant seem to fetch any of the FirstNames...

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if let results = managedObject?.executeFetchRequest(fetchedResults, error: nil) as? [Users] {
    let someObject = results[firstName]
}
```

By

```
var firstNames = [String]() // empty array to keep the firstNames
if let results = managedObject?.executeFetchRequest(fetchedResults, error: nil) as? [Users] {
    for user in results  {
        firstNames.append(user.firstName)
    }
}
```

My code snippet adds the firstName of every user in the firstNames array. You have to realise that *someObject* in your code is not a single User but an array of Users.

Comment: thanks for this but im not trying to pull a single user im trying to pull an array of firstName's...

Comment: That's a minor addition, just edited the code to create an array of firstNames.